# How to really preview GIMP fonts?

Tags: fonts, gimp

I want to choose proper GIMP font for my purpose, so I would like to browse through all of them visually. But, having to choose GIMP font based on a single letter "Aa" (as provided by the text tool) really sucks:

[image]

Googling around, I found there are [three ways to open font dialog in GIMP](http://ahmed.amayem.com/gimp-preview-fonts-3-ways-open-fonts-dialog-md/), but all of them are equally bad.

Is there some better preview of all the default GIMP fonts? In the GIMP program itself or at least somewhere on the Internet.

Comment: I've used gimp for 20 years and wanted this.  I don't want to use a font manager, I want to see my text, in my colours, in the image, in the font that I'm interested in without messing around.  Anyway I saw someone say you can use the mousewheel on the fonts dialog (not the popup) but no use to me as I am on a laptop.

Comment: @Cameron You can use a mouse on a laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: **GIMP (up to v2.8) can not do that for you**.

But there are workarounds. At first, one side note: there are no *"Gimp fonts"* — all fonts come from your system.

So we all can use the system font viewer. Or, as an alternative, install an external viewer for the appropriate operating system. Here are several useful links:

- [SO question](https://askubuntu.com/q/8452/400409) about available font viewers
- [.NET based Fontviewer](http://fontviewer.net/#system-requirements)

---

*PS. After all, it is embarrassing, that the official Graphic Editor doesn't provide many basic features for image editing (please, correct me if I'm wrong). For small pictures I always use small editors, for large projects - I go to Fiverr...*

Answer (score 4):

There are no "Gimp" fonts. The fonts are on your system.

Google for some Font Manager on your operating system, and choose the one that has previews.

---

On Windows I use the font manager that comes with Corel Draw, but there a some interesting free tools:

xiles.net Nexus font has a nice interface, can make some groups of your favorite fonts and preview all installed ones.

This is really interesting fontba.se because I used it to download the google fonts to a folder, but has many features that you need to explore.

Comment: The system font manager only sees fonts that are installed for the system, not the ones that have been added only to Gimp.

Comment: Aha! Wow, I didn't know that! Ok, in this situation I can just use Microsoft Word to select fonts in more user friendly way - they have font name typeset in that font. My OS is Windows 10 Professional. If there is a better preview tool I would be grateful for that. Thanks!

Comment: @xenoid: Don't know your platform, but the Windows font tool in Windows 7 and 10 can preview uninstalled fonts too and even install them for you. Just right click the font and select Preview. But note that Gimp will only show installed fonts.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis thanks! Anyway, right-clicking each font when you need to select out of 100+ isn't a solution :)

Comment: @Tomas: that's true. Not really the ideal way to choose a font. Although, you should only click those that *may* be useful. If they don't look good in the font selection box of Gimp, no need to click them. But I agree, that is still not a very good way.

Comment: On Windows 10 you can preview the installed font set via the new controlpanel, search for 'fonts'.  You can get to a page that previews all the installed fonts.

Comment: In above comment I said controlpanel, but I really meant settings. Anyway, these are both valid methods to show installed fonts, according to the detailed explanation in https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/103617-preview-fonts-windows-10-a.html

Answer (score 2):

In GIMP 2.10.x you can use the mouse scroll wheel to go through all the fonts. If you don't have a mouse, then buy one.

Just type some text. In the tool options mouse over the font icon, and scroll the mouse wheel

[image]

Comment: Not working. Some attributes changes when using Tool Options window (size, antialiasing, box, adjusting). Others don't (font, color). Looks like these two windows are not synchronized. In small window you cannot "scroll" through fonts.

Comment: @sZpak It is working. I just tested it in GIMP 2.10.34 (the most recent version as of today).  You need to type some text, with the text tool, then mouse over the font icon in the tool options for the Text tool, then the scroll wheel works.  Also note that if you have typed some text, then used other tools, you will need to click on the text with the text tool to get the cursor back inside the text box before trying this.  Also this only works on live text layers, not rasterized text. It's also possible to do the same in the Fonts dialog using the up and down arrow keys on your keyboard.

Comment: For some reason it works for a new text layer but not for the one I have already in place.  The layer is not rasterized. I wonder where is the problem. I'll let you know if I find out. :) Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: @sZpak It works for all live text layers, even for those that you may have created earlier, but you must click on the text with the text tool, to put the cursor inside the text box. If the cursor isn't in the text box it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think he is right the font viewer on Gimp is a total pain. Also I don't want to open yet another program when looking at fonts. Gimp needs a larger font interface that's easier to navigate and shows the fonts more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is Windows only.  Open File Manager.  Go to C:\Windows\Fonts (or equivalent).  For convenience, hit F11 to expand the window to full screen.  You should now see large icons, one per font variant.  Inside the icon is text written in that font, in the primary script for that font.  That should help you choose your font, remember its name.  Now Use the text tool to add your text.  It will be in the wrong font, no worries.  Note the popup that appears above the text.  Use -a to select all the text.  If you type in the font name box (upper left), it becomes a font name search box and shows you matches.  Choose the name that you want to change the font.  You can also set the text size and color here.